# Video Player Local Storage

Tags: javascript, video, local-storage

I want to store video `duration` and ``src to local storage, but this code not working. The video `src` and `duration` showing in inspect element application local storage but not working for the video player.

```
window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
  let setDuration = localStorage.setItem(
    "duration",
    `${mainVideo.currentTime}`
  );
  let setSrc = localStorage.setItem("src", `${mainVideo.getAttribute("src")}`);
});

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let getDuration = localStorage.getItem("duration");
  let getSrc = localStorage.getItem("src").src;
  if (getSrc) {
    mainVideo.src = getSrc;
    mainVideo.currentTime = getDuration;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem certainly lays right here

```
localStorage.getItem("src").src
```

You are trying to read the property `src` but `localStorage.getItem("src")` returns a `string` or `null` not an `object`. Remove the `.src` part and that error will be resolved.

I'm sorry if that wasn't your problem. If so please provide further information about your problem or any error messages.

Comment: Error successfuly resolved thanks a lot.